# Symfony asks to type-hint SqlWalker constructor parameters

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql, type-hinting

I have a problem.
I am creating a custom **walker** for **Doctrine** **DQL** query and it extends the `SqlWalker` class.

```
class UseIndexWalker extends SqlWalker
```

And the symfony asks to autowire the args of SqlWalker __construct.

```
Cannot autowire service "App\Object\UseIndexWalker": argument "$query" of method "__construct()" has no type-hint, you should configure its value explicitly.
```

This is how I add walker to query in controller/repository.

```
$queryBuilder->getQuery()
   ->setHint(Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER, UseIndexWalker::class)
   ->setHint(UseIndexWalker::HINT_USE_INDEX, 'event_search1_location_idx')->getResult();
```

How would one fix such a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the file to excludes property of  **services.yaml** file